# Passing an id from a select list in a form, getting "non-object" error, Laravel-4

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, selectlist, laravel-routing

On a dashboard page, I've created a select list in a form that lists the names of components; the value that's passed from the select list is obviously the component id. On pressing submit, the user is routed to a page that displays the data about that component. Should be dirt simple...

Controller:

```
public function showDashboard()
{
    $components = Component::lists('name','id'); ...
    return View::make('dashboard', array('components'=>$components, ...))
}
```

dashboard.blade.php:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('components.show', $components->id), 'method'=>'get')) }}
{{ Form::Label('id','Component:') }}
{{ Form::select('id', $components) }}
{{ Form::submit('Show Component', array('class'=>'button')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I've tried various ways of doing this, and get a different error every time. The above code doesn't even let me display the dashboard page -- I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" error. Clearly, it's not liking $components because that was passed as a list array and not an object. As I said, I'm sure this is dirt simple, I just can't figure out the proper syntax, and Laravel docs aren't giving me the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this out. I had posted a similar question here subsequent to this one, and rather than repeat the answer, it is here:

[How to pass id value from select list to controller when controller expects an object? laravel-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635953/how-to-pass-id-value-from-select-list-to-controller-when-controller-expects-an-o)

The very short version: change Route::get to Route::post. Details with code in the link above. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the dropdown, or the lists method, but rather in your form opening. Here, you have `$components->id` as an argument to the route, but `$components` is an array and you can't access an `id` property on it.

Comment: Thanks, I get that -- what I can't figure out is how to construct the form opening to pass the id value to the target route, and then have the target page use that id to display the data for that id. So, here's my currently corrected form opening:    {{ Form::open(array(
   'route' => 'components.show',
   'method'=>'get'
   )) }}

Comment: Thanks, I get that -- what I can't figure out is how to construct the form opening to pass the id value to the target route, and then have the target page use that id to display the data for that id. So, here's my currently corrected form opening: {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'components.show','method'=>'get')) }} -- this displays the drop down select list correctly: <select id="id" name="id"><option value="2">Component Name</option>. But when I press Submit I get "Trying to get property of non-object" error. The target controller uses: $component = $this->component->find($id);  :(